# Can python fileinput's openhook option stack together both hook_compressed and hook_encoded?

Tags: python

I'm reading a compressed file; the uncompressed data should be interpreted as UTF-8. So I'd sort of like to use both `hook_compressed` and `hook_encoded`, in the `fileinput` `openhook` parameter. But, I don't see a way to stack/wrap them.

On the off chance the existing hooks took file-like objects, not just filenames, I gave this a try:

```
def myhook(file,mode):
    return (fileinput.hook_encoded("utf-8"))(fileinput.hook_compressed(file,mode),mode)
```

...but no such luck.

Answer (score 1):

Rather old question but `hook_encoded` just uses the `codecs` module. So you can use `fileinput.input(mode="rb", open_hook=fileinput.hook_compressed)` and then decode the result using `codecs.decode`. However, if whatever part of your application you pass this on to knows how to deal with encoded strings then you're fine not doing anything.

Or did you find another answer yourself?